# How to extrude outwards?

Tags: extrude

So I'm watching this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY

And at 42:37 he instructs us to "Extrude outward". I'm not sure how to do this, because just scaling seems to not do what he's doing.

Comment: click e for extrude and then s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't really extrude outwards, it's actually a two step operation composed of an extrude and a scale commands.

Select the desired geometry and press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and immediately after <kbd>Right Click</kbd> to cancel the operation.

It will look like it did nothing, but it actually created duplicate faces that are now overlapping the original.

Now just scale it outwards by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>.
You may optionally press <kbd>.</kbd> (period key) before scaling and change the transform pivot to the 3D cursor scale outwards relative to its position, instead of the selection center.

Comment: This is incorrect. See my answer.

Comment: That is the *Extrude Along Normals* operator, which only works for 3D shapes that have normal information. It doesn't work on 2D shapes like the one illustrated in the video.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually extrude outwards or inwards. You just have to extrude each face along its normal. Just select the faces you want to extrude and instead of pressing <kbd>E</kbd> for "Extrude", press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for Extrude context menu and select "Extrude along Normals"... and that is it.

Answer (score 0):

Just extrude like normal and press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, based of on what he's doing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.