# Any way to fix this cylinder?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I messed up along the way and I do not want to have to start over any way to fix this mistake without deleting the cylinder?

Comment: In Edit Mode elect the vertices in question and press "X" do delete them.

Comment: What do you mean by "Fix"? if you mean you messed the top part, then just do as Dontwalk said and select the messed up vertices, (Preferably with the key B, box select). then produce with the modeling?

Comment: Please be descriptive about what you are trying to do and what exactly has gone wrong.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the problem now how do you add vertices?

Comment: Use the extrude tool. Check out this link https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/curves/editing/introduction.html?highlight=extrude. Select the top ring of vertices by pressing ALT + Right Click between any two vertices on the top ring. Then press E to extrude.

Answer (score 2):

Ok to turn my comment into an actual answer:

Within Edit Mode: 

Select the vertices you want to delete by pressing <kbd>C</kbd> and clicking <kbd>LeftMouseButton</kbd> on the ones you wish to delete. Use the mouse wheel to change the size of the brush(press rightmousebutton confirm selection), OR use the box-select tool, <kbd>B</kbd>, and drag. Afterwards press <kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>V</kbd>.Then you'll want to exturde the top ring of vertices using ALT+Right click, which is used to select loops.
[image: loop select] do <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>RightMouseButton</kbd> anywhere between two vertices on the top loop to select the loop(the red lines illustrate some examples of where you can ALT right click). Once selected press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude. It will be automatically stuck along the local Z axis. If you don't want that press <kbd>Z</kbd> again. Press <kbd>LeftMouseButton</kbd> to confirm placement.

**Related Links:**

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/curves/editing/introduction.html?highlight=extrude#extending-curves

[How to extrude outwards?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53104/how-to-extrude-outwards)

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/mesh_structures.html#loops

Answer (score 0):

In Edit Mode select the vertices in question and then press the “X” key to delete them. You can also press Command + “Z” to undo your last move(s). You can control the number of times that you can “undo” in your User Preferences in the Editing Tab. If you make a change in you User Preferences be sure to save them.